What is the maximum of $ \frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}$?
I have asked this here. Due to inactivity and no satisfying answers, I am asking here. Hope that's okay.
We know the global maxima of the function $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$
is $n$ (thanks to this question), but

what is the global maxima of
$\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}, \text{ where $a$ is a constant term?}$

Background: It represents the intensity of a narrow-slit diffraction grating but in a more specific application.
Attached is a plot of the maximum absolute value vs $a$ for different $N$. It seems the below equation gives an approximation of the maximum (don't know why, it was a guess)
$$N + \frac{sin(2Na)}{sin(2a)}$$
The cyan colored plots are plots of the above equation while the red, blue and black plots are obtained by finding the maximum programmatically.

MATLAB code used to produce the results of above image:
N = 40;
x = -pi/2:0.001:pi/2;
a = -pi/2:0.01:pi/2;

% figure;
for i = 1:length(a)
    y = sin(N*(x + a(i)))./sin(x+a(i)) + sin(N*(x - a(i)))./sin(x-a(i));    
    temp(i) = max(abs(y));
    % hold on;plot(x,y);
end

figure;plot(a,temp)

Here is a link to the desmos graph

For large $n$ the maxima of the op's function $f(x)=\frac{\sin(n(x+a))}{\sin(x+a)} + \frac{\sin(n(x-a))}{\sin(x-a)}$ are very close to $x=\pm a$, where one of the terms is $n$ and the other is $\ll n$. So a first approximation is $f_\mathrm{max}=f(\pm a)=\frac{\sin(2na)}{\sin(2a)}+n$.

Hi @FredHucht, why is the maxima very close to $x = \pm a$?

Because each term in the sum contributes one sharp maximum, one at $+a$ and one at $-a$, and is dominant near that point. The addition of the much smaller other summand shifts the maximum only slightly. So to first order we can assume that the maximum does not shift, and only add the contribution of the smaller one to the dominant part $n$.
